# How can I figure out which NFS client mounted which directory on NFS server?

Tags: ubuntu, nfs

I have a storag server in my network, and the server exported several directories as NFS target. Such as `/raid0/folderA`, `/data/after_2018`, `/data/shared_data` and all of these targets allow any IP to mount it. Now I need to figure which server mounted which directory. Because all these use same listening port and NFS clients not always mounting all NFS target, so I can't only check TCP connection. Dose NFS server it self have any way to figure this out?
Thankyou in advance!

Comment: As far as I remember, the NFS server is stateless and doesn't remember who mounts anything. Why do you need to know which client mounted what?

Comment: I have a list about which server should mount which NFS target. And I have the privilege of NFS server, but due to some management reason I don't have access of every NFS client for now. But I need to observation if every NFS client mounting directories correctly.

Comment: Perhaps the database mentioned in https://serverfault.com/questions/831173/nfs4-how-to-log-mount-requests helps.

Answer (score 0):

Run this command on NFS server

```
showmount -a 127.0.0.1
```

This will show mountpoints on NFS Clients in format `IP:/mountpoint`

Also you could run this command on any NFS client in format

```
showmount -a A.B.C.D
```

where `A.B.C.D` is NFS server address.

`showmount` command also knows options `-d`  (List directories that have been remotely mounted by clients) and `-e` (Print the list of shared file systems)

Comment: Note that `showmount` may not show NFSv4 mountpoints at all, since NFSv4 won't use the NFSv3-and-older style `mountd` service, which the `showmount` command relies on. In server's `/proc/fs/nfsd/clients/*/info` you can see the NFSv4 clients' IP addresses, source ports, hostnames and "implementation names" (on Linux clients, essentially `uname -a` outputs) - but not which mountpoint(s) the client might be using.